# why Viewmodel instance in fragment leaking

Tags: android, memory-leaks, viewmodel

I am using viewmodel and live data to observe changes in a edittext view like below. It's showing me the memory leak while I run the app with leakcanar: Mainactivity.fragviewmodel leaking.

```
FragViewModel model;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(FragViewModel.class);

    final Observer<String> savedTextObserver = newName -> {
        list = MainActivity.quotesDatabaseClass.quoteDao().getQuotes();
        adapter.setData(list);
    };
    model.getTextToSave().observe(requireActivity(), savedTextObserver);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    fragmentEmojiBinding = null;
    model = null;


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `.observe(requireActivity(), savedTextObserver);` in a Fragment's `onCreateView` is never the correct thing: that's saying you want to observe using the Activity's lifecycle, which will continue even if you remove the Fragment or put the Fragment on the back stack.

Instead, you should use `.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner()`, savedTextObserver); `to get the Lifecycle specifically associated with the Fragment's view, which is the correct scope for any Observer that updates your Fragment's UI (such as your`setAdapter`).

Comment: Do I need to do removeobserver() on onDestroyView() too?

Comment: No, not when using `getViewLifecycleOwner()` - that's the whole point, it is automatically destroyed when the View is destroyed.